# MYSQL: Adding records based on foreign keys

Tags: mysql

My question might be better understood if I provide a (simplified) example of the scenario. I have two tables, Event and Course. The Event table contains EventID, CourseID, and EventDate. The Course table contains CourseID, and CourseName.

I would like to add a new Event. I understand that the query normally would be as follows:

```
INSERT INTO event
(EventID,CourseID,EventDate) VALUES ( NULL,'2','2011-03-01');
```

But instead I would like to update Event by providing the CourseName instead of CourseID. How would I go about doing this?

Edit: Apparently there isn't a way to do this with just a MYSQL query. I'm trying to do this in PHP and attempting to allow a user to update the Event record. Obviously it would be convenient for the user to add a new event based on the name of the course, preferably with a dropdown box.

Thanks

Comment: Usually it is done outside of sql, with select options in forms displaying names but returning ids, why do you need it in sql?

Comment: I'm actually trying to do it with PHP, I just figured there would be a query for it in mysql. I'll update my post to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Event ( EventID, CourseID, EventDate )
SELECT NULL, C.CourseID, '2011-03-01'
FROM Course C
WHERE C.CourseName = 'Course Name Goes Here';
```

Answer (score 0):

This one one thing that you could try. Though you may want to include the date in your query or some other way to make sure you are uniquely identifying the record you are looking for.

Another thing that you could think about is storing the event id, when you bring up the reference to the event you would like the user to update.  Then you would ensure that you are only updating the record that you intend to.

```
update Event set ....
  where courseID=(
    select courseID from Course 
      where CourseName like ''
  )
```